# Background push notifications in Xamarin

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Please consider the following issue:

I am using the following plugin for Xamarin to perform push notifications, I am attempting to get this running on both iOS and Androids.

https://github.com/CrossGeeks/FirebasePushNotificationPlugin

I am also using the following PHP code to send push notifications to the device from a website.

```
$fields = array
(
    'to' => $ID->notification_token,
    "content_available" => true,
    'priority'=>10,
    'notification' => array('title' => 'You have a new message', 'body' => 'Hooray', 'sound'=>'default', 'vibration'=>'default'),
);

$headers = array
(
    'Authorization: key=' . PUSH_NOTIFICATION_API_ACCESS_KEY,
    'Content-Type: application/json',
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send' );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
$result = curl_exec($ch );
curl_close( $ch );
echo $result;
```

Now the issue is on iOS I find that the push notification is reliable and runs perfectly when the app is in the foreground, but as soon as I background it (or lock the screen), they stop coming through *until* I foreground it again, then all of the notifications sent while it was in the background all come through at once.

I have enabled background processes in my `info.plist` as according to the plugins "Getting Started" guide.

I have tried changing `content_availiable` to `content-availiable`, also moving it into the notification array, also setting the value of it to `true`, `'true'`, `1` and `'1'`

I have also tried adding `"alert" =>  ""` to both the notification and the overall payload, however I still can't get it to work, outside of the foreground unlocked state.

I also notice that nothing appears to be triggering in the actual notification list (Pulled down from top of screen), the only way I know that the notifications are being received is from playing a certain sound file as it comes through and writing in the debug log.

Any assistance will be appreciated, thanks for your time.

Comment: Any solutions on the same ? I am also getting the same issue. Not getting notification when my app is in foreground for iOS, getting notification when app is in background. Please help, if you found any solution.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure your message Json has the `{"content-available" : "1", "alert" :  ""}` attributes if you want it to show up on iOS when not running in background.

As for Android, push notifications really are not 100% realiable, there are device specific impediments that may block your notification from showing up.

There might be a "test send" feature on Firebase (I've only used Azure Push Hub so far) so you can try and see if your message Json is configured correctly.

Comment: Hi there, I managed to improve the droid accuracy by making it high priority, and changing it from a data message to a notification. I'm going to test the content-available method tonight and see if it helps iOS.  thanks for your time.

Comment: Hey Lucas, sorry for the late reply, been super busy. Android appears to be working perfectly, but I still can't get iOS running outside of the foreground-unlocked state. I've just put up an edit, I'm also going to award a bounty on the question. If nobody provides an answer for iOS, I will award the bounty to you based on your android help. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I would try sending a Data Message instead

```
$fields = array
(
    'to' => $ID->notification_token,
    "content_available" => true,
    'priority'=>10,
    'data' => array('title' => 'You have a new message', 'body' => 'Hooray', 'sound'=>'default', 'vibration'=>'default'),
);
```

Comment: I've just tried this, but unfortunately the same result. Comes through just fine when foregrounded, but nothing backgrounded or locked

Answer (score 0):

Use ApnsConfig to show alerts in iOS when the app is in background. This worked for me.

```
var pushMessage = new FcmMessage
        {
            Data = new Dictionary<string, string>
                    {
                        { Constants.PushMessages.MessageId, $"{message.MessageId}" },
                        { Constants.PushMessages.TopicId, $"{message.TopicId}" },
                        { Constants.PushMessages.Type, $"{message.Type}" },
                        { Constants.PushMessages.Title, message.Title },
                        { Constants.PushMessages.Content, message.Content },
                        { Constants.PushMessages.CreatedBy, message.CreatedBy },
                        { Constants.PushMessages.CreatedOn, $"{message.CreatedOn}" }
                    },
            Token = registrationToken,
            Apns = new ApnsConfig
            {
                Aps = new Aps
                {
                    Alert = new ApsAlert
                    {
                        Title = message.Title,
                        Body = message.Content
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        await FirebaseMessaging.DefaultInstance.SendAsync(pushMessage);
```